# Only display the Value of a ForeignKey and not <model> object(...) in Template

Tags: django

I have a Django Modal with ForeignKeys.

```
class clientvul(models.Model):
    
    client= models.ForeignKey(client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    VID=models.ForeignKey(vul, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Path=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    Product=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    isActive=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
               fields=['client', 'VID'], name='unique_migration_host_combination' 
            )
        ]
```

I've created a qs `vul1=clientvul.objects.all()` in a View.
When I try to display the Data on a Template it Displays vul object(4803) I want to only display the 4803.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `object.pk` etc. everywhere you would not like to display the default string representation of a model's object, or you can overwrite the default object string representation like:

```
class clientvul(models.Model):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pk
```

You can also have something like this etc.:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.client} - {self.Product}"
```